# Connection refused to Kubernetes Pod from CronJob on the same Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I am currently working with Kubernetes on Google Cloud with a microservice architecture. Where in a cluster I have different Pods and each of them can communicate with the others via curl using a ClusterIp.

My problem is that I need an endpoint of one of these pods to be called from time to time using the ClusterIp. For this I created a CronJob which curls the endpoint of the pod, but it always returns:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx port 8080: Connection refused
```

This is the yaml of the cronJob.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronjob-test # name of the CronJob
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *" # run every minute
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: cronjob-test
              image: appropriate/curl
              args:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - curl -X POST http://${CLUSTER_IP}:${CLUSTER_PORT}/api/test/
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use ClusterIP for it, you suppose to use services.

Comment: Maybe include how your service and deployment looks like to determine if there's an issue there. Also, clarify if you're able to cURL other pods hitting the ClusterIP and if so, if you're cURLing them via IP address or FQDN.

Comment: I can perform a curl among all pods successfully, using the ip address and port generated by the Service of type ClusterIp created.

Comment: What are the CLUSTER_IP and CLUSTER_PORT (8080) values? Is it possible that CLUSTER_IP is the cluster IP of the CronJob's pod itself? In any case, unless fixed (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#choosing-your-own-ip-address), Service-s cluster IPs change when the Service objects are recreated for some reason so using Service names is usually preferable.

Comment: It works if I put a delay (sleep 10) before de curl, why could this be happening

Comment: It might have something to do with your image, have you tried switching it? Additionally, it might also be related to the container not being completely ready, you can try [adding probes to the pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) generated by the CronJob.

Answer (score 7):

`istio-proxy` sidecar is **VERY** slow to start up in comparison to your workload, in which only `alpine` is included.

This will lead to problems when your workload is already sending out requests, whereas `istio-proxy` is not yet ready, or even not yet registered in `Pilot`. This is why it works if you `sleep 10` before actually sending out the requests.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, [dns-pod-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) contains the solution what you need.

Here, you can find the FQDN for services if you want to use services. You can also find the FQDN name for pods (with/without headless service), if you use pods.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. After I disabled the istio sidecar injection by adding label istio-injection=disabled to the namespace. It all works fine.